# Get current text, convert it and replace current with new

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create a converter for wordpress which converts some shortcodes of the content textarea into other shortcodes (I thought about using php).

So pseudocode:

```
get current text
change [shortcode1 param1=test] to [shortcode2 param2=test]
replace current text with converted text
```

My problem is, that I dont know, how I can get the current text of the textarea and convert it.

All this should be possible by pressing a button located on top of the textarea (called "Convert test").

Comment: are you looking to override a shortcode or do a find and replace in the database?

Comment: No, not replacing it, because I need the parameters and give them new parameter names. And I also dont want to convert all pages, this should only be performed on the current viewed page by clicking a button. (may jquery would be better??)

Comment: You will want to create a TinyMCE plugin to do this. http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Buttons

Comment: Yes something like that, but how can I manipulate the current text?

Comment: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorials:Creating_a_plugin, there is also a plugin called 'searchreplace' that is already built that you can probably add to wordpress' tinymce install, I would start there with that, and edit to suite your needs

Comment: here is a link to the plugin https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/tree/master/js/tinymce/plugins/searchreplace